# RKE2 Worker won't connect to server: invalid username/password combination

Tags: debian, kubernetes, rancher, rancher-2

I'm creating a rancher RKE2 cluster for the first time. I followed the [quick start guide](https://docs.rke2.io/install/quickstart) and created a server and a worker.

Both are Debian 12 Virtual machines on an ESXI hypervisor. Both VMs can ping each other.

When I try `systemctl start rke2-agent.service` on the worker, it stays stuck. When i press Ctrl+C then type `systemctl status rke2-agent.service`, i get this: `Waiting to retrieve agent configuration; server is not ready: failed to retrieve configuration from server: https://127.0.0.1:6444/v1-rke2/config: 401 Unauthorized`

On the server side : `systemctl status rke2-server.service` gets me `Failed to authenticate request from 10.0.0.101:56286: invalid username/password combination`

I don't really understand what username/password this is talking about since i didn't see anything about passwords nor usernames in the wiki. For the sake of testing I allowed all ports both on server and worker side with ufw. I'm stuck

config.yaml file on worker vm:

```yaml
server: https://10.0.0.2:9345
token: xxxxxxxx::server:xxxxxx
```